# Issue loading admin.site.urls after changing the settings folder

Tags: django, django-urls, django-settings

I re-organized Django,the following way:

```
config
 - settings
     - base.py
     - local.py
 urls.py
 wsgi.py
```

In `base.py/local.py`:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'
```

In `manage.py` I changed:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")
```

In `wsgi.py` I changed:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")
```

I have the following error on runserver:

```
\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 269, in get_urls
    path('%s/%s/' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls)),
AttributeError: 'AccountAdmin' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

It is related to this line:

```
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # Django 2.0 syntax
```

If I comment that line I get the following error:

```
django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 79, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'AccountAdmin' object has no attribute 'model
```

The app admin is in installed app, I don't know what is creating this issue.

Comment: Did the below answer helped you? If not, please give some feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... Several things happen here. One thing at a time:

Under your `settings` dir put an `__init__.py` file with the following contents in it:

```
from .base import *

try:
    from .local import *
    LIVE = False
except ImportError:
    LIVE = True

if LIVE:
    try:
        from .production import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

By putting this inside the `__init__.py` file, you can reference to your `settings` file simply with `'config.settings'`, leaving `local` or `production` unreferenced (the `__init__.py` will handle them).

Now that this is out of way, change **both** `uwsgi.py` and `manage.py` to:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')
```

Assuming that you have done all that, it should work (that's how I structure my projects for years and had never any problems). Otherwise, please update your question with project structure and `base.py` and `local.py` contents to work it out.

Comment: @thanks; I redone the django layout with packages as started to work; I have a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186359/accessing-django-templates-after-modifing-the-django-layout-structure, please take a look