# Accessing Django Templates after modifing the Django layout structure

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

I re-organized Django,the following way:

```
config
 - settings
     - base.py
     - local.py
 urls.py
 wsgi.py
```

also apps:

```
- apps(level0)
  - acc(level_1)
   - users(level_2)
     - templates
       - users
    - acc_control(level_2)
  -att(level_1)
    - notes (level_2)
    - notifications (level_2)
  - mark(level_1)
- config (level0)
- templates(level0)
```

Some apps are directly in apps folder, ex mark, others are in other subfolders, ex users

```
   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))) 


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

My issue is regarding templates access, because I receive the following error:

```
\apps\acc\users\templates\users\templates\users\detail.html (Source does not exist)
```

is repeating the internal folder;

In the `View` the template is set as:

```
 template_name = 'users/templates/users/detail.html'
```

I tried also:

```
 template_name = '/users/detail.html'
```

Comment: There's not much to say here. In the error page you have a nice key value pair table showing you what the value for each setting configuration is. Check that against what your actual path is and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `users/templates/` prefix when you set `template_name`. As long as you have `'APP_DIRS': True` in your `TEMPLATES` setting, the app directories loader will check the `templates` directory for every installed app, including `users/templates`

```
template_name = 'users/detail.html'
```

Comment: thanks, the second try didn't work because I used '/' at the begining